# Excel report was too big which makes system to hang

Tags: .net, sql-server

Iam working on live project. **current issue is** When client wants to view Excel Report (one year) using sql server as database,Excel report was too big which makes system to hang.what could be the possible reasons...
1) The Excel report is of 90 MB size (one year report)
    We suggested client to use Power Pivot tool...but he is not ready to upgrade his 32 bit system.using older version of Excel.

Comment: No Danish...customer retrieving data form sql server....the file size is almost 90 MB.His system hangs while creating report in Excel sheet..He is not willing to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Performance of Excel in this scenario is highly dependent on the version (32bit vs. 64bit) and the amount of system memory that the desktop has that you are trying to run this report on.

What I have found that works in the past with this scenario are a couple of methods:

1) Export your query to a CSV file and then load into excel (i.e. generate the output file from SSMS or another tool)
2) Increase the amount of memory in the machine by either expanding the memory cards or running only Excel at the time.
3) Spin up a virtual machine which has higher performance specs and run the query from there

Comment: Thank you BrianAtkins.client point of view we cannot go with option 2 and 3. I will try 1st option. we have used normal query to retrieve data.do we need to go with indexing or stored procedure?? Client not ready to upgrade his system.

Comment: You could write a stored procedure and then have a scheduled task to export on a regular basis.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you BrianAtkins...my client using 32 bit system with windows 7 home edition and using excel 2010..while generating yearly report in excel connecting to sql server,his system hangs… reason is 18 million rows dumping into excel at once..what could be the reason…will power pivot support for that configuaration…..